# Is there a way to customize the android accessibility service button?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I have created my own accessibility service that is overriding the accessibility button and wanted to see if there was a way to customize the button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can only take them to the list of accessibility services. You cannot automate much of the accessibility stuff because of the implications it has.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).